# NAS delay file-availability

Tags: nfs, mount, network-attached-storage

I have two machines accessing to a NAS on the same network (OVH), when I update or create some file in machine 1 after I try to read it from machine 2 and it's not accessible, even not visible for a several seconds.

After a some research I found a solution, changing `actimeo` to 1 in `/etc/fstab`, I saw this parameter change 4 parameters that control file and directory cache to 1s. I am not sure if decrease this cache expiration is safety because some defaults parameters are near to 60s.

Can anyone add more information and explain if it's safety to decrease it? Is it better to add `noac` option?

Comment: What exactly are your two client machines doing? Do they really need an identical view of the whole filesystem? 
I mean, disabling cache with `noac` can significantly decrease write performance. Disabling attribute caching with `actimeo=1` or `actimeo=0` increases latency. I guess you'd need a set of benchmarks if you want to optimize your NFS performance.

PS. Pardon my ignorance, what's OVH?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov OVH is the hosting company. Regarding both machines, they are writing and reading small files, most of times not bigger than 1MB, one of this machines is a webserver and read those files in some user request. I know disabling `noac` can decrease the performance but I don't think that I really need high performance with these kind of files. Thank you.